# Amplify signal going to motor of kids electric car

Tags: amplifier, step-up

I have a 6V electric kids car (similar to power wheels). I want to convert it to 12V. Since it has a lot of electronics that are dependent on 6V I was just thinking of keeping the electronics fed by 1 6V battery and using an extra 6V battery to amplify the power to the wheel motor. The motor is rated to take 12V. How would I do this? (I’m a CS major, not an EE major but would love to learn).

So I had the following ideas but I don’t know how to wire it:

1. Connect 2 6V batteries in a series and use a step down converter to convert to 6V for electronics and somehow amplify the signal to the motor to 12V
2. Connect a 6V battery just for electronics and then amplify the motor signal using another 12V battery (would rather not have 2 batteries). I don’t know how to amplify the signal.

Comment: It depends on how the motor is controlled. If the 'electronics' is truly directly controlling the motor (rather than something like a relay) it may not be so easy and it may be easy to damage the components.

Comment: I would like to feed the electronics from the 6V battery but have the 2nd 6V battery amplify the output of the motor when it gets a signal.

Comment: Does the car go in reverse, and if so how does it do it? Does it have variable speed or just full on or off?

Comment: The car goes in reverse. Full on and full off. No variable speed.

Answer (score -1):

Since the motor can take 12V, you can try to use 12V.

6V+6V in series connection to get 12V. Or just buy a 12V battery.
[image: This is how to do series connection]

Edit for misunderstanding the question:

For Electronic 6V input:

- Use buck converter or DC-DV converter 12 to 6V use separate cable for connecting to your electronic device.
- Or you can try to draw 6V from your one of your 6V battery (6+6 in series) and the 12V to your motor
  This is why I post the picture of 12V in series.

For motor:

- Did it really can handle 12V or there is another driver for the motor (BLDC driver)?
- If it is a direct DC motor (without any controller) then you can connect it to your motor via the relay, the relay should be 6V which is I guess from your original battery this is all operated with 6V. With this relay, you connecting it to your battery for your motor.

I hope this one clears it up. It should be simple.

Edit 2 for someone asking the source or link of the picture above.

[CLICK HERE](https://www.batterystuff.com/kb/articles/battery-articles/battery-bank-tutorial.html)

Edit 3:

Here is the diagram for easy to modify your electric car kids.
[image: Here it is]

The red line is positive(+) and the negative(-) is black

Because the original question **doesn't provide the board picture** and connection, **I can only assume** the board has 2 cable inputs for power (+ and - from 6V) and the output is 2 cables to the motor **(6V output?)**

Please check whether your toys have manual gear for reverse or it has digital switching on your board to makes polarity changing. **If your toys have manual gear for reverse or it doesn't even have a reverse function then my diagram could work**

If you are worried about the unbalanced draw on each battery, you can use an extra device such as a converter or buck converter from 12V to 6V DC-DC before your electronic board. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Will the electronics etc survive 12v? You should consider that, not just the motor.

Comment: I know how to connect the batteries in a series. That would fry the electronics. I want to keep a 6V feed to the electronics but I want to amplify the signal voltage to the motor using a 2nd battery when it gets a signal.

Comment: edited my answer sorry for misunderstanding.. you can check now

Comment: You need to provide a link or citation for the graphic you copied into your answer. We want to give credit to the original creator.

Comment: check the bottom part

Comment: I like this idea: “ Or you can try to draw 6V from your one of your 6V battery (6+6 in series) and the 12V to your motor”. That’s what I want to do - Can you draw a diagram of what the connection would look like or describe it better. I don’t understand how I would wire this...

Comment: I was thinking of using a step-down 12V -> 6V converter to connect the electronics but if I connect the 12V battery directly to the motor won’t the motor just continuously spin? I need to amplify the 6V signal the motor is getting from the electronics, not give 12V continuously to the motor.

Comment: @Denis Drawing the 6V from only one battery is a bad idea, as it means your batteries will drain unevenly.

Comment: @Denis i will try to make the diagram for you.. but it would take time a bit.
It wouldn't continuously spin because you are using a relay. wait I will try to make it a simple diagram.

Comment: @Denis done please check it again.

Comment: This is great! I see how to do it. Is there a way to vary the voltage using a relay? I.e. let’s say i want to try 8V on the motor first and then slowly go up to 12V.

Comment: How would this work for reverse? Wouldn’t it just connect the circuit so the car goes forward?

Comment: @denis you can try using dc buck converter that can change the voltage from 0-24V (usually but you can check yourself) with input meets your standard (12V). It have reverse feature?

Comment: please add picture of your board and connection. Because i can't tell you what is what from blind position :)